# PHPBB3: Ban and delete inactive users (spammers waiting for admin accept) with a single action

Tags: phpbb3

PHPBB3 with double opt-in plus individual verification of registration by admin.

Each day, a number of forum spammers register on the site, and we get the list of new users waiting for the admin to accept. We are able to see directly from the user name + email address whether it is a wanted user or not, and in uncertain cases we check with other tools.

We want to ban and never hear again. Doing this in phpbb3 is a multi-step process, it seems:

(Press Users and groups in ACP)

1. Select the user with a mouse click
2. Select IP Ban from the dropdown combo
3. Press Submit
4. Press Back to previous page
5. Select Email ban from the dropdown combo
6. Press Submit
7. Press Users and groups tab again, repeat on next inactive user

Finally, after (7*n) mouse clicks:

1. Press Users and groups
2. Press Mark all (and maybe unmark wanted users)
3. Select Delete in the dropdown combo
4. Press Submit

Total mouse clicks: 4+7*[number of users]. What we would WANT to do:

1. Select Mark all (or alternatively, check-mark a number of user names).
2. Press [Ban by IP, by email, delete and Goodbye forever] -button.

Is there a way in PHPBB3 to achieve this? We cannot let the list grow, for example in order to wait for an auto-expire, that would make it too hard to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Mass delete is only possible for inactive users. But mass banning is possible by using the "Users and groups/Ban emails" form.

But why you want to ban them? They are probably bots so banning them may not help at all.

I suggest you to consider the following counter measures.

Set "User registration settings/Account activation" to "by user (e-mail verification)". That way, spamming is much harder because then, a spammer has to have a working e-mail address.

Install a CAPTCHA script that prevents most spambot registrations. A simple extra question on the registration form will prevent 99.9% of the spambots.

Limit user rights of new users and set "User registration settings/New member post limit" to 1 or 2, so that new spammers can't disturb real users so easily. This makes your forum less attractive target to human spammers.

What comes through after these counter measures can be handled manually like you have done so far.

Comment: Croco thx. But there is absolutely no way we'd allow the spammers to accept themselves; then each spammer Id could post one or two Nike ads, and could create a new Id each day. Naturally they do have a never-ending source of email addresses and a fair set of proxys (which we try to exhaust now). The "mass" ban emails requires one to manually copy/paste the addresses (we'd want to simply check-mark them). An improved captcha might be something, though - we'll check that, thx. But clearly phpbb lacks the desired "mass * (delete AND BAN)" feature? Could be so simple...

Comment: @Stormwind I believe the feature is missing because devs don't think it as a good tool against bots even though an admin might feel like he is punching spammers to the face by deleting and banning them. For example, if your IP ban list grows very large, it might start to affect performance and block legitimate users too. It's also very time consuming to fight against these pests like that.